# How I can get string truncate method in Magento 2 like Magento 1?

Tags: magento2, php, helper

In Magento 1 I use:

```
Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($string, $length, '...', $remainder)
```

How I can use a native method to truncate strings in Magento 2?

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2 I reckon you need to use `Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager`

After injecting it in your constructor you can do:

```
$this->filter->truncate($string, ['length' => $length, 'etc' => '...', 'remainder' => $remainder])
```

Here is an example from a native Magento 2 file: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/Sales/Block/Order/Item/Renderer/DefaultRenderer.php#L168

Comment: Is it necessary to add "remainder" or is it ok if I ignore it?