# Magento 2 truncate string

Tags: magento2, product, theme, magento-2.1

I'm writing a new theme for magento 2.

**I need to truncate product short description in my template.** In version 1 there was a method in `core/string` helper, so i was able to do something like `Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($string, $length)`.

In Magento 2 i can't find a way to do that without rewriting a `ListProduct` class.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/118142/2380

Comment: yes, but how to do that just in new theme, without writhing new module?

Comment: you can't you will have to override the list class to be able to access the filterManager

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager` for that:

```
$this->filterManager->truncate($string, ['length' => $length]);
```

Comment: i get `Cannot access protected property Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor::$filterManager` using your way

Comment: @Styopchik well you will have to use dependency injection to inject it in your class constructor.

Comment: in theme? how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

for this you can use core php for this.

```
$string = (strlen($string) > $length) ? substr($string,0,$length).'...' : $string;
```

Comment: this way can breake html tags from short description

Comment: it will count string length and string length is > than youe length then it will break length

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, i know. But i found the following solution(class) in Magento 2 Framework.

> vendor/magento/framework/Filter/Truncate.php

The class have same code like:

> app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php -> helper('core/string')