# Limit product length in frontend

Tags: magento2.4.2

Magento 2.4.2

[image]

I want to limit the length of the products name while displaying it in front end. I tried all the ways recommended earlier but no luck. I found the code as mentioned below

escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getName()) ?>"
                                            href="escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>">
                                            escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>

Can anyone please help to sort this..

Comment: This answer might be useful https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/275916/7863

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below sample code.

```
<?php
$productName = $_item->getName();
$len = strlen($productName);
?>
<a class="product-item-link" href="<?php echo /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getProductUrl() ?>">
    <?php echo substr($productName,0,50); ?>
    <?php if($len > 50) echo '...'; ?>
</a>
```

**substr** function will truncate product name (string)

Answer (score 0):

You also do it with pure css. no need to update phtml file.

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Ref: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Get you product name class and apply above css.